# What is a "double-boxcar filter"?

Tags: python, scipy, smoothing

I am smoothing data according to a research paper, and it says they apply a "double-boxcar" filter of width X". I know how to boxcar filter in python, i.e signal.boxcar and signal.convolve, but I'm not sure how to interpret this statement.

Do you guys think they are doubling box width or are they just smoothing twice over?

Comment: Is the signal or data you are smoothing two-channel?

Comment: Not really a programming question, and as much might be better suited for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A [box car filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function) is essentially a crude low pass filter. Presumably a double box car filter is two separate filters applied over different ranges to the same signal or an iteration of the filter on the same signal.

Comment: I think I got it: https://www.flickr.com/photos/seetwist/3666763028/ :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it belongs in dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yeah I apologize about putting it here. I didn't really know which one to post in. Ok the double iteration sounds about right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably means they apply the boxcar filter twice.  The Central Limit Theorem tells us that repeated box convolutions will converge to a Gaussian convolution [1].  2 passes is equivalent to a "tent" filter; usually 3 passes are used for a nice smooth approximation.

[1] http://nghiaho.com/?p=1159

Comment: AH! This is exactly was I was looking for. After reading that link, it makes a lot more sense, both statistically and in terms of what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!